# unix shell, tail -f from last occurence of pattern

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have very large log file, which contains log of service restart messages. After I initiated service restart with external command I need to tail this log file from last occurrence of reboot message and check following messages to confirm correct restart procedure. I'm analysing messages by python, so only find last occurrence and follow file needed, then i check output line-by-line and simply close connection when read everything I need.

```
.... # lots of previous data
[timestamp] previous message
[timestamp] Rebooting... # from tis point i need to track messages
[timestamp] doing thing
[timestamp] doing other thing
[timestamp] doing final thing # final point, reboot successful
[timestamp] service activity message #
```

How can I perform such tailing?

```
tail -f <from last Rebooting... message>
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

give a generous buffer value, reverse, extract, reverse

```
$ tail -1000 file | tac | awk '1,/Rebooting/' | tac
```

or, replace `awk` script with `!p; /Rebooting/{p=1}`

Comment: OP is using `tail -f` which follows the file as it is written, I'm not sure it will work this way ; if it does, you should include the `-f` flag in your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
tail -fn +$(awk '/Rebooting/ { line = NR } END { print(line) }' log) log
```

which uses `awk` to find the line number of the last occurrence of the pattern and then tails starting at that line.

This still scans the entire file, though.

If you're really doing it from python, you can probably do better by searching the file in reverse directly in python.